# Differentiability of $\frac{xy^2(x+iy)}{x^2+y^4}$ at 0

Tags: complex-analysis

This function is defined to be 0 at z=0  and the value at the rest of the points is given by that formula

I tried to use the Cauchy Riemann equations.

Here, $u=\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^4}$

$u_x=\frac{2y^6x}{(x^2+y^4)^2}$

I'm getting $u_x=\frac{0}{0}$ at x=0, y=0. Similarly, I calculated $v_y$ and that's also 0/0 at z=0.

I think I'm not doing it right. Please give me some hint.

Comment: $u_x$ is only equal to that expression when $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$. Recall that $u_x$ is actually a limit, and not just a rule applied to an expression

Comment: @DavidPeterson I was thinking about the same thing. But what do I do to check differentiabiity at 0? I was thinking of  f(z)-f(0)/(z-0) as z tends to 0. But I don't know how to manipulate that expression when z can approach from any dorection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(z)=\frac{xy^2(x+iy)}{x^2+y^4}$$

So $$\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=  \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}\tag{1} $$

Now we will try to see why limit of the expression $(1)$ does not exist if we approach origin from different directions.

If we let $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$ along any line $y=mx$ then

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{m^2 x^{3}}{x^{4}m^4 +x^{2}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{mx}{x^{2}m^4+1}=0$$

And if we take the limit along the parabola $x=y^2$ then 
$${\displaystyle}\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y^{4}}{2y^{4}}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore we conclude that function is not differentiable at $0$ as if we approach origin from different directions we are getting different limits.

Comment: What about the Cauchy Riemann equations though? Could they be used here too?

Comment: CR equation is just a necessary condition. It is not sufficient. If function does not satisfy CR equation at point then we can say that it is not analytic at the point. Converse need not be true.

Comment: What is the sufficient condition then? And, Is analytic at a point the same as holomorphic at a point?

Comment: @ryder If we add the condition that partial derrivatives exist and they are continuous then it becomes a sufficient condition for analyticity of a function at the point. In complex analysis holomorphic functions are same as analytic functions. So yes. But you need to be careful in real analysis. Analytic is a broader term used for function which can be expressed as a convergent power series.

Comment: Complex analytic= Holomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy.$ Then

$$\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0} = \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}.$$

On the $x$-axis, this is $0,$ while on the path $(x,\sqrt x)$ this equals $1/2.$ Thus the limit of this as $x+iy\to 0$ fails to exist, which shows the complex derivative $f'(0)$ fails to exist.